# Error while activating virtualenvironment of python in windows 10

Tags: python

```
'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied. To change the      
execution policy for the default (LocalMachine) scope, start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator"  
option. To change the execution policy for the current user, run "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser".       
At line:1 char:1
+ set-executionpolicy unrestricted
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPoli  
   cyCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "RemoteSigned"

Comment: Run this command before activating virtual environment